# Is ToString() here good, bad, or simply redundant?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

Both of these are accepted by the compiler:

```
ssMinnow = listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID].ToString();
ssMinnow = listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID];
```

Is one way preferable to the other? ToString() or not ToString(), that is the question.

Comment: if you know that `listStrLineElements` is **always** a string, I would not use it, it make no sense casting to the same type.

Comment: Isn't listStrLineElements a List<string> type? The name suggests that.  If it is not, change the name accordingly.

Comment: This is also accepted by the compiler: `listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID].ToString().ToString().ToString().ToString();` but that doesn't mean it's good code ;-) If it's already a string, why call ToString?

Comment: Not germane to your question, but I would suggest that in C# you SHOULD_NOT_WRITE_CODE_LIKE_IT_IS_1973. `VesselToAvoid` is perfectly clear and doesn't look like the code is yelling at the reader.

Comment: What is the type of `listStrLineElements` and what is the type of `ssMinnow`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not only redundant, but also is dangerous: if `listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID]` happens to be `null`, your application is going to throw an exception if you use `ToString()`; without `ToString()`, it would simply assign `null` to `ssMinnow`.

Answer (score 5):

If `listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID]` returns a string, then yes, it is redundant. if it returns some other type, then no, it is not redundant.

Answer (score 3):

in General your don't need to invoke the `ToString()` method is the object type returned is already a `String`.

in your example we cannot tell that as `ssMinnow` does not show the declaration type :I assume you have used `var` keyword which will work with both of them or `listStrLineElements[VESSEL_TO_AVOID]` returns already a `String`

Answer (score 1):

Simply redundant.  I prefer to leave off ToString() where its not needed but its a judgement call.

Comment: In what way is it a judgement call, the judgement is "shall I write redundant code or not", surely there is a correct answer here.  No you shouldn't write redundant code.

Comment: @Ben In the sense that its not incorrect to leave it there, and some people prefer to be explicit even when not needed.  As I said, I leave it off but its not necessarily incorrect not to do it that way.  Especially considering that we don't know that this is a string based on the info provided, it could just be a datatype with an implicit conversion defined.  The phrasing of the question, "good bad or redundant" also implies that the person asking sees a difference between something that is incorrect or something that is wrong,whether you wish to acknowledge that or not.

Comment: It IS incorrect to leave it there, the fact that there is a call to `ToString` implies that it is needed, when it is not.  This makes the code less readable as another dev may waste time trying to figure out WHY this code is there as it seems to serve no purpose. Some people chose to write bad code, it does not make it right. I do acknowledge there is a different between bad and redundant in that that are more types of bad code than redundant code, but redundant code is always bad.  Note that I do not consider code added for readability purposes to be redundant, it serves a purpose.

Comment: @Ben No, its not incorrect to leave it there.  Random capitalization doesn't make it so.  ssMinnow could be of a type that's not string but has an implicit conversion defined, and he could be clarifying intent. Given the incomplete code snippet provided there are plenty of cases you could make where it would be redundant from the compiler's standpoint (not the arbitrary definition you're using) but not necessary.  It looks like you're just spoiling for pedantic debate though, so w/e.

Comment: dasblinkenlight also makes a good point in that if the property is null it will throw a null ref exception.

Comment: @Ben yes, that's a good point, unlike the one you're making.  Even with his point taken into account, without seeing all the code you can't make a blanket statement as to what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ToString if you are already returning a string. You're just adding unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so simple as stated.  Redundant, possibly; good or bad, a matter of opinion.  Since toString() will be called anyway if the object is treated as a string somewhere, the explicit use of toString() can serve as a signpost to the developer reading the code.  The explicit call describes more of the original intent than leaving it as an assumption for the compiler to fulfill.